# jQuery - Button Is Unresponsive, But Why?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, class, modal-dialog

I have a backend where you can click to delete an entry, and I have jQuery UI coming up with a confirm or deny modal, when I have one entry the modal works, when I have two or more entries, the button does not work, the button.click action is assigned to a class I know that it can't be assigned to an ID that's only for one.

jQuery -

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog({
           autoOpen: false,
           modal: true,
           buttons: {
               'Confirm': function () {
                window.location.href = 'delserv/1';
                },
                'Cancel': function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
        $( '.deleteServ' )
          .button()
          .click(function() {
            $( '#dialog' ).dialog( 'open' );
          });
    });
</script>
```

HTML -

```
<button class='btn btn-primary btn-mini' class="deleteServ"><i rel='tooltip' title='Delete Server' data-placement='top' class='icon-trash icon-white'></i></button>
```

**Keep In Mind I'm using PHP foreach to loop through entries, only when one entry is shown, the modal works**

Comment: what is `.button()` for??

Comment: It was a part of the example I had found, I deleted it, no fix.

Comment: Have you tried putting only one class attribute in your `<button>`? Like this `class='btn btn-primary btn-mini deleteServ'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Nix I agree with you. The html element button does not require .button() in the jquery code.

Try removing and write something like this

`$( '.deleteServ' ).click(function() {
            $( '#dialog' ).dialog( 'open' );
          });`